# airmon-ng with internal wifi adapter

Tags: backtrack

i'm using backtrack 5 using vmware 10 workstation .when i type `airmon-ng` it doesn't shows anything .

[image]

but when i type `ifconfig` i got following output .

[image]

this is my internal wifi card[divice manager].

[image]

how ever i have made following network settings

[image]

i searched a lot and found lot of answers but still didn't get a clear answer ..

my question is if i have only internal wifi adapter [not external usb adapter] ,can't i use it ??

and is there any way to use internal device with backtrack...i have see that "airmon not support your internal device" some where on internet ..so is there internel wifi devices which doesn't work with backtrack -`airmon` at all ?? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can only use USB wifi devices for aircrack-ng if you run it in a virtual machine. If you want to use your internal wifi card try it with a live version of backtrack

Greetings

Comment: is it really impossible ?